# Laravel 4 - get Records where entry in N:N Relation exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have some trouble with an Eloquent Query.

I Have 3 Tables:

### products

- ID
- NAME

### media

- ID
- FILE

### product_media

- PRODUKT_ID
- MEDIA_ID

Now i am trying to an get random result set from the Product table, but only records where
an media file exists.

Something like this (does not work..)

```
Product::orderByRaw("RAND()")->media()->wherePivot('file', '=!' , '')->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
Product::orderByRaw("RAND()")->has('media')->take(10)->get();
```

It will take all products that has at least one media. I assume that you store in `product_media` only entries where `file != ''`